# What exactly is a command in Latex?

Tags: macros, tex-core

In other programming languages I have come across a command is a verb; it is something for the computer to do. The things that commands act upon are called variables and these come in various types. We can have a string variable or a numeric variable or a date variable and so on, and the code usually instructs the commands to do something to the variables: @ Row(24) Col(65) Print(date), for example.

In Latex, anything that starts with a backslash is called a command, so `\author{text}` is called a command despite the fact it does nothing. It is really just the declaration of a variable. Not only that, it is a variable I am unable to use, directly. If I type `\author` Latex tells me I have made an error, and if I type `\author{}` Latex assumes the author has no name. So the "command" `\author{text}` is, in real computer programming terms neither a command nor a variable.

The "command" `\title{text}` is the same. If I actually want to display the title within my document I can either write it directly, by hand, or I can define a new command, `\newcommand{\mytitle}{title text}` and then in the body of my document type `\mytitle`. So as far as I can determine, the command `\title{text}` does exactly nothing for my document. It is not a command in the, "do something useful" sense, it is not a variable in the, "store some data" sense. So what exactly is the proper definition of "command" in Latex?

Comment: Perhaps you'd enjoy reading the chapter on macros in [*TeX by Topic*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) by Viktor Eijkhout.  The purpose of TeX is quite different from other 'programming languages'....

Comment: I think the negative point isn't quite fair.  The OP has a genuine question.

Comment: Think of `\author` and `\title` as what is called _setters_ in other programming languages. In Java, you would probably call them `setAuthor()` and `setTitle()`, respectively. They set internal ("private") state that is then used by other commands ("methods"), in this case it is `\maketitle` that uses the "private" state and actually does typeset it.

Comment: for the record, knuth calls any alphabetic string beginning with a backslash a *control sequence* (more specifically, a *control word*).  i don't remember the term "command" being used in this sense in the texbook; other people started using that term because it's shorter, and more easily understood (if imperfectly) by a newbie.

Comment: Why do you say `\author{text}` does nothing? Of course it produces no text in the document and no messages on screen, but surely code in many programming languages will do that. One can even type commands in a command line window and have apparently nothing happen.

Comment: @barbarabeeton LaTeX calls macros for document-level use 'commands'

Comment: @JosephWright -- i certainly won't argue that.  whether the first person to use the term "command" in print was leslie lamport or someone else, i don't know, and can't check for a couple of weeks.  but don knuth had a reason for not using that term.

Comment: See also:  [What is the difference between 'macro' and 'command'? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468508/what-is-the-difference-between-macro-and-command)

Answer (score 17):

LaTeX *commands* do *do* something.  For example, in the case of `\author`, the command does the following:

```
\gdef\@author{#1}
```

That is `\author` *globally* defines a macro `\@author` to store the *name* of the author for use later.

`\@author` is then called when you place `\maketitle` (depending on how a particular class defines `\maketitle`).  So, `\author` is a command that takes 1 argument and stores that argument in another, internal, command `\@author` which can be called later on.

The commands `\author` and `\title` are usually set in the *preamble* to your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Martin}
\title{My document title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

 Content of my document.

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's a bit more difficult to get the content of `\@author`.  For example, in the `article` class, once you call `\maketitle`, the content of the macro `\@author` is cleared.  You could work around this by doing something along the following lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Martin}
\title{My document title}
\makeatletter
\let\my@author\@author
\newcommand\getauthor{\my@author}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle

 Content of my document.

 The author's name is \getauthor.

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I've done here is save the content of `\@author` in my own macro `\my@author`.  Then I define a command to retrieve the content of my macro.

If you want to access the title of your *document*, then you should do something similar to what I did for accessing the author:

```
\makeatletter
\let\my@title\@title
\newcommand\getmytitle{\my@title}
\makeatother
```

What's import here is that the `letting` be done after you've called `\author` and `\title`.  Otherwise, you'll most likely get an error message.  That is `\@author` and `\@title` are defined to issue errors if you try to use them and they haven't already been defined by call from `\author{...}` and `\title{...}`.

### Deeper issue of what a command is about

Some commands in LaTeX take an apparently "immediate" effect such as `\textbf{...}` which will set the content of the argument in a **bold** font, `\section{...}` which will start a new section whose title will be that of the passed argument.  Some commands require multiple runs of LaTeX before *things* settle down:  for example,  `\tableofcontents`.  Some commands work in tandem:  `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}`.  Some commands don't seem to take any effect until *something else* happens:  such as in the case of `\author{...}` and `\title{...}` whose effects are not noticeable until you call `\maketitle`.

Depending on what kind of a background you're coming from, it can be a bit tricky thinking about LaTeX macros/commands.  There are various complicating factors:  The asynchronous nature of how LaTeX makes various formatting decisions can lead to many headaches if you're not aware of them.  Some commands *expand* when you call them (in the mouth of LaTeX).  Other commands *wait* until they're in the gullet.
Generally, it's a very broad topic that is probably best handled on a case by case basis.

The suggestion in the comments to your question to read `TeX by Topic` is a very good suggestion.  If you're just trying to write a document and the commands aren't doing what you're expecting them to do, there are quite a number of good resources.  You might want to check out some of the titles suggested at [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/22413).  Of course, if you really want to get into the nuts-and-bolts of it, there's `The TeXbook` by Donald Knuth (but if you're just getting started, it's not the first place I would recommend someone look).

If you want to see how individual commands are defined, there are several approaches.  If you have access to a command line and you're working on a Linux box or Mac, then you can try to `locate` a given class and look at the actual code.  Alternatively, you can call from the command line `texdef` (or `latexdef`--though I've not had success with `latexdef` on my Mac), to see the source code for a command:

```
 $ texdef -t latex -c article maketitle -s
```

which will spit out to your terminal the definition that the `article` class uses for `\maketitle`.

You can also use `texdoc source2` to look at the documentation for LaTeX kernel.  Or `texdoc article` to get the documentation for the standard document classes.

Comment: A very full and informative answer from A. Ellett, so I must thank you for the effort which is appreciated, but it doesn't actually answer the question I thought I had asked. Maybe the question reads differently to other people than it does to me.